# Recreate table if it is manually deleted

Tags: entity-framework

We ran into a problem with one of our customers this week who manually deleted a table from an entity framework database using Management Studio. When they went to run up our software application it would throw an exception due to the fact that the table does not exist. The framework won't recreate the table because it is present in the MigrationHistory table. If I delete the corresponding row from the migration history, the entity framework will then recreate the table.

What we'd like to be able to do is catch this particular exception and have a way for the entity framework to recreate the table if it doesn't exist without having to delete the correspond row in the migration history. Is there a setting for that particular context that will allow us to do this? In this particular scenario, data loss isn't important since the table is something we use for temporary tracking so recreating it if it doesn't exist poses no risk to existing data.

Many thanks,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

From my experience there is no way you can achieve this with Entityframework migrations. EF migrations is generally extremely simple mechanism. It does not perform any checks on db structure. Its knowledge on db structure is based only on __MigrationHistory table, migrations can be applied or reverted only as a whole, never partially. Migrations system behaves well if it is the only one to manage db structure, if there are some other things (like users) mixing the strucutre on their own then it leads often to conflicts that needs to be manually resolved. If you would like to have inteligent migration system then, I am afraid, you have to write it on your own. The proper solution for the client is to revoke administrative priviledges from unexperienced users who are not cautious about interactions with the system (I assume this was the case). If they refuse to do so and you have to repair the system because of their actions then this is a perfect opportunity to send them yet another invoice for the repair (isn't that beautiful?).

Comment: I've just realised nearly 1 year later that I never replied to thank you for your response. It wasn't too much of a problem in the end, our software system makes daily database backups so it was simple enough to restore from one of those. We decided not to invoice for the repair in the end :).